# Quick GUI for your own utilities

Tags: user-interface

What do you guys use if you want to make a quick and dirty Windows GUI as a utility helper for your coding? I had been using AHK but since I do a lot of work in C# I wondered if it were more convenience.

Basically I'm looking for the simplest way to pop a window with some fields and do a little text processing in a Windows desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Python and tkinter, or tcl/tk is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for code prototyping and small tests. Even though its meant for more database stuff, I'm sure you could punch out a GUI really fast in there and save it for future testing.  It has a lot of support for C#, but also quite a few other languages. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but that's what I would use.